# How to get BitmapFont width libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have started going through a LibGDX project from a while ago, which uses a `BitmapFont` and to space it correctly I would use `font.getBounds(text).getWidth()` where `text` is a `String` and `font` is a `BitmapFont`. However no that I look through the [LibGDX API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) I can't find the `getBounds()` function nor any repacement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question has answer here-> [How get a String Width in Libgdx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600547/how-get-a-string-width-in-libgdx/16606599#16606599)

Comment: @ksap Thank you, I searched multiple times but somehow must've missed that.