# Libgdx how to get the total width of a text? (BitmapFont)

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

How to get the total width of a BitmapFont text?

```
font.draw(batch, text ,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - /* text width */ /2,450);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How get a String Width in Libgdx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600547/how-get-a-string-width-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`GlyphLayout`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.html) to calculate the width of some string using a particular font:

```java
GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout(font, text);
float textWidth = layout.width;
```

Don't put this in the `render` method, though. It is a good idea to calculate and store this value once in `create` or `show` and then just use the value in your `render`.