# How to get the natural fontsize of bitmapfont?

Tags: libgdx, bitmap-fonts

If I have a bitmapfont such as;

```
fonttexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonttest.png"), true);
font= new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonttest.fnt"), 
                     new TextureRegion(fonttexture ), true);
```

Is it possible to retrieve or deduce the natural fontsize used on the associated png texture file?
The *.fnt file itself specifies this on the first line;

```
info face="Calibri Light" size=32 bold=0 italic=0 charset=""
```

Its that **32** I am after in code.
I couldn't see a method on BitmapFonts class to directly get it, but there was various other height related attributes possible to get.

I tried recreating the size from those but didn't have much luck.

```
float baseToAssent = font.getCapHeight()+font.getAscent();
float baseToDecent = -font.getDescent();Decent);            
float fontHeight = baseToAssent+baseToDecent;  //too small, like 11 not 32
```

Not being a fonttographer? fontophile?...umm...graphic designer, I am probably putting the pieces together wrong, or maybe just lacking one.

In either case, *any way to work out the font size used in the fonttest.png would be helpful.*

Thanks

**Usecase**;

I am manually using that texture with a distance field shader. Knowing the textures natural font size is useful in order to accurately scale the text and lineheight to any requested font size without ever resizing a image and thus losing quality.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to get the font size specific, however you can easily get the String width and height of a font using a [GlyphLayout](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.html), like this:

```
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonttest.fnt", false);

    GlyphLayout glyph = new GlyphLayout(font, "TextMessage");
    float width = glyph.width;
    float height = glyph.height;
```

Read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600547/how-get-a-string-width-in-libgdx) if you want to learn more about GlyphLayout and BitmapFont.
Experimented quite a bit with a 32px font, like yours. The String "W" seemed to be 29px wide, which was the widest I could find, so it's definately not precise if what you want to archive is the size exactly.

You could do a little hacky method, reading the .fnt file as a text file and looking for the Integer after "size=", pretty much like a [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file work, it will be less efficient but will return exact value.

Comment: Indeed. I tried something similar at first too with much the same results. As I'll be reusing this code a fair bit I was trying to be as accurate as possible, so I might have to do the hacky method.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work. Got to be careful using it though, as you can (and I do) also adjust the lineheight. That values thus only correct if it hasnt been changed. My (hackish) solution is thus maintaining a hasmap of fonts and their native sizes.