# LibGDX: Creating a the amount of textbutton on a screen depending on the length of a word?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I was thinking of a 4 Pics 1 Word-like answering method for a game, where there is a blank and a set of characters are displayed for the player to click to type in the possible answer. I was just thinking how can you make the amount of textbutton shown is same to the amount of character of a word (length of a word)?

Answer (score 0):

[related to get width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600547/how-get-a-string-width-in-libgdx)

```
// for BitmapFont API < 1.5.6
float width = font.getBounds(yourWord).width;
float edgeWidth = 5f; // indention 
yourTextButton.setWidth(width + 2 * edgeWidth);

// for BitmapFont API >= 1.5.6
GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout();
layout.setText(yourWord);
float width = layout.width;
float edgeWidth = 5f; // indention 
yourTextButton.setWidth(width + 2 * edgeWidth);
```

You also can use [Table](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) for the task, it should calculate size itself

```
Table table = new Table();
TextButton textButton = new TextButton(yourWord, skin);
table.add(textButton);
```